# how to get data from exact chtml class agility pack

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

I want to extract not the whole web-page but only text from one class, I want text from td class="result-neutral" and I don't know what is wrong with this code:

```
<td class="result-neutral" xseid="xz1nBfht"><a href="/hockey/russia/khl/ska-st-petersburg-metallurg-magnitogorsk-xz1nBfht/">3 - 2 </a></td>
```

And this is C# code:

```
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
        HtmlWeb hw = new HtmlWeb();
        doc = hw.Load("htt
var scoreNodes = doc.DocumentNode.Descendants("td").Where(d =>d.Attributes.Contains("class")&&d.Attributes["class"].Value.Contains("result-neutral"));

        foreach (var item in scoreNodes)
        {
            result += item.OuterHtml + Environment.NewLine;
        }
        Info.Text = result;

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The `OuterHtml` returns html with start & end of the element. Don't you want `InnerHtml` or `InnerText`?

**EDIT:**
This snippet works for me:

```
const string html = @"<html><body><table><tr><td class='result-neutral' xseid='xz1nBfht'><a href='/hockey/russia/khl/ska-st-petersburg-metallurg-magnitogorsk-xz1nBfht/'>3 - 2</a></td></tr></table></body></html>";
var doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(html);

var scoreNodes = doc.DocumentNode.Descendants("td").Where(d => d.Attributes.Contains("class") && d.Attributes["class"].Value.Contains("result-neutral"));

string result = "";
foreach (var item in scoreNodes) {
    result += item.InnerText + Environment.NewLine;
}
result = result.TrimEnd(); // the result is "3-2"
```

Comment: @NickShepard So, you want the content of attribute "class"?

Comment: yeas I do. In the end I want to get score which is here 3-2. On the web page from which I'm exctracting data there're several scores all in class called result-neutral

Comment: I actually don't even get this page if I use a break point to trace it

Comment: And what you get, if you use InnerText property?

Comment: nothing. the problem is in query. If I write just Descendants("td"); I get all td's, but I use query to get exact class and this query is wrong and I don't know how to fix it